# How to run an ADF pipeline only when a specific other pipeline is not running?

Tags: azure-data-factory, scheduling

In my ADF I have two pipelines as below:

I have a pipeline **'Pipeline A'** which alters a specific data blob 'Blob X', and it **runs once in a day with a dataset dependency** (it is a dated dataset and only on that file creation this pipeline runs).

There is another pipeline **'Pipeline B'** which does some cleanups and all on multiple data blobs including 'Blob X' and this pipeline **runs every 6 hours once**.

As both pipelines modify same blob, when both pipelines execute in parallel (happens rarely, but happens) it is leading to weird failures. So, **how can I make a dependency to 'Pipeline B' such that it should not execute when 'Pipeline A' is executing**.

*Note:* *'Pipeline B' uses tumbling window trigger, so upon failure it will make sure it executes for a successful execution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Web activity to check whether the Pipeline is in progress or not based on the REST API
Pipeline-Get

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/get?tabs=HTTP

Reference :
mrpaulandrew.com/2019/11/21/get-any-azure-data-factory-pipeline-run-status-with-azure-functions/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/60424/get-status-of-pipeline-triggered.html

You can keep this web activity within an Untill loop and once the pipeline is done, proceed for the next set of tasks to avoid any conflicts.